# Match chart legend entry formatting to source data in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, format, legend

How do I get the format of the legend entries in an Excel 2013 chart to match the formatting of the cell the series name is from? My series title needs to be a mix of italics, subscripts, etc, but I don't know how to customize this label at all. I either need the format to carry over from the source cell or just to be able to override the legend entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not ideal, but it works. Just delete the legend label from your data source and then insert -> shape -> text box in its place that is formatted to your liking. Example image attached of what I think you wanted.

[image]

**Disclaimer: This chart in no way makes any sense.

Comment: This is also the best solution I have arrived at. Not elegant by any means but it should work.